# Create a dictionary from excel named columns as Keys

Tags: excel, vba

The columns that I'm using are from E to BH but they are named. For example, Column e is named "problems". I am trying to create a dictionary from a cell value which will act as a primary key in order to query the ranges from E to BH.

For example, if I have a cell with value "Late payment" located on E6, I want to be able to get the ranges from columns E6 to Bh6 and then be able to query the other columns like "Summary" which is on column AQ and be able to get the related summary which is on AQ6.

I have been thinking how to approach this problem, I think a dictionary of the wanted range would be the best idea, because of the {Key, value} pair data set where a named column can be a key the value will be what's in the cell and I want to be able to know the other values on a column like summary for example.

Below is what I'm doing for now to get the other values. I don't have much experience in vba and only started using it a week ago for work.

```
Set cdata = Worksheets("Table")
Dim newRange As Range
dim keyWord as String
KeyWord = "Late payment"
Dim Summary as String


Set rng1 = cdata.Cells.Find(What:=KeyWord, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    'Sets the range based on cell value
    Set newRange = ccdata.Range("E" & rng1.Row & ":BH" & rng1.Row)
End If

'Gets value and sets column from row number
Summary = cdata.Range("$AQ$" & rng1.Row).Value
```

Comment: By "named", do you mean the columns are actual named ranges, or that the name is the column header?

Comment: Yes it's the column header name. They are all on the second row

Comment: So you want a dictionary with key:header and value: an array with index = row and the array value being the value of the cell?

Comment: @Warcupine pretty much but I wanted to get the other values by being able to refer to the column name if that's possible. and BigDen, I'll see what I can do

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me. Could you post some code on how you would use this dictionary? It doesn't have to be correct, even pseudo code is OK. That could pretty much clarify it.

Comment: @VBasic2008, I was thinking of something along the line with how warcupine did it. I'm just about to test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for. I included the header in the array to keep the index = row.

You'll also have to be aware of the fact that creating an array from a range creates a 2d array so it will always be `arr(row, 1)`. The 1 won't change because each range consists of 1 column.

```
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim lc As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'Add Microsoft Scripting Runtime to early-bind
    
    With Sheets("Sheet5") 'Change as needed
        lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 5 To lc
            lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            arr = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lr, i)).Value
            dict.Add .Cells(1, i).Value, arr
        Next i
    End With
    
    'return the value like this: dict("problems")(6, 1)
```

Comment: So basically this mapped the entire sheet ranges e to bh  to the dictionary? Also the dictionary takes a column and cell coordinates to return a cell value?

Comment: Yeah, E to lastcolumn. The dictionary is key:Header item: Array(row, 1) so if you're looking for row 6 in problems it would be `dict("problems")(6, 1)` If you want to do only to BH I think that is mapped to 60 if I did that math properly.

Comment: Ok so I can use the value of  rng1.Row in my existing code to use with yours.  Basically `dict("problems")(rng1.Row)` I'll try that

Comment: Don't forget you will need it to be `(rng1.row, 1)` because converting a range into an array will create a 2d array.

Comment: By the way my header columns are on the second row. Do I just change this line `lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` to `lc = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` ?

Comment: Yes and you'll need to change `dict.Add .Cells(1, i).Value` to `dict.Add .Cells(2, i).Value`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the calculation of `lr` before (outside) the loop? I mean, do it for a 'significant' column, so the arrays are of the same size. A nice idea though.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I wasn't sure if their columns had jagged rows, if it's a nice rectangle then yeah.

Comment: I get typed miss match trying to use debug.print dict("problems")(rng1.Row, 1) not sure. It's returning a string right

Comment: Its a variant array so it can take anything a variant can, a string shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Actually never mind. It worked. Thanks a bunch